# Seeing only your own data in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

This seems like a fundamental question, but I haven't found a clear answer.  I'm using the spring-security-core plugin with Grails, and I have S2Users who have many Portfolios, and Portfolios have many Transactions.

When I go to a scaffolded view to examine Transactions, how do I know that each user is only seeing his own Transactions?  Conversely, how can I create a user that can see all Transactions of all users?

It's not clear to me what the default behavior is, and how Grails/Spring-Security knows whether a particular domain class should be visible to everyone versus ones that are only for the associated user.

Comment: No, Spring Security will not restrict data automatically. You have to create the proper queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I go to a scaffolded view to examine Transactions, how do I know
>   that each user is only seeing his own Transactions?

You're going to have to modify the scaffolded views for it to work correctly:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
def list() {
   def authenticatedUser = User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username)
   def transactions = Transaction.findAllByUser(authenticatedUser)
   [transactions: transactions]
}
```

The above will only allowed authenticated users to access the list() method and will get all Transactions for the logged in user.

> Conversely, how can I create a user that can see all Transactions of
>   all users?

You don't create a user that can see them all, you create a method in your controller that allows a particular user to see them all, for example:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN'])
def list() {

   def authenticatedUser = User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username)
   def transactions = []
   if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
       transactions = Transaction.list()
   }else{
       transactions = Transaction.findAllByUser(authenticatedUser)
   }
   [transactions: transactions]
}
```

Something like that, anyway.  Tweak as needed.

Comment: You can use `springSecurityService.currentUser`. And the query, to be precise, needs to be like `transactions = Transaction.withCriteria { portfolio { eq 'user.id', springSecurityService.currentUser.id } }`

Answer (score 3):

There are plugins that help you with this. I'm using the [Hibernate Filter plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) for that exact purpose, it helps you to restrict the SQL so that each user only can see his/her own data. You can then override with your own implementation of the HibernateFilterFilters, that disables all filters if the user has ROLE_ADMIN (copy the source from the plugin and adapt).

There are also some plugins for multi-tenancy, but the maintenance of those seem to be unsure to me. I like the Hibernate Filter plugin, it's simple and straightforward - but you have to change all .get()-calls to .findById() because how the plugin hooks into Grails/GORM.

Comment: Definitely a useful pointer.  But what does vanilla Grails provide along these lines?

Comment: AFAIK nothing. You have to handle it yourself, using own code or a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If the data access rules are more complex and need to be enforced in all the application code, you can use [spring-security-acl](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-acl/) plugin.