# Grails Logged in username owns created record

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm sure this has to be one of the most common things done in programming, that is how to associate a certain form submission with a certain logged in user.

I've been trying for quite some time and I just end up running in circles and getting error after error.

My question is, what is the correct way to have a user own the record they submitted?

I've tried many options, unsuccessfully. :\ I even tried the less secure method of creating a String field and inserting the current user in a hidden field in the gsp and that even didn't work right.

static belongsTo = User

in the domain class, great but that only lets me see it in the User form.

Maybe the problem is how it scaffolds. Generate Controllers, Generate Views do a great generic list for ALL records. I need this list to only show THEIR records. but then additionally I need my admins to see ALL records.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

SalesOrderController.groovy

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
def list(Integer max) {     

    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.max.toInteger() : 10, 100)
    [salesOrderInstanceList: SalesOrder.list(params), salesOrderInstanceTotal: SalesOrder.count()]
//      def user = params.id ? SecUser.findByUsername(params.id) : SecUser.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
//      [salesOrderInstanceList: SalesOrder.findAllBySoldBy(user), salesOrderInstanceTotal: SalesOrder.count()]
//      if (!user) {
//          response.sendError(404)
//          return
//      }
}
```

class SalesOrder {

```
static searchable = {
    user(component:true)
}

enum JobStatus {
    PENDING, APPROVED, COMPLETE
}

enum JobType {
    INSTALL, REPAIR, WARRANTY, TINT
}

enum PaymentType {
    INSURANCE, CASH
}

enum InstallLocation {
    INSHOP, HOME, BUSINESS
}

enum InstallTime {
    MORNING, MIDDAY, AFTERNOON
}

JobStatus jobStatus
JobType jobType
PaymentType paymentType

String custFirstName
String custLastName
String custBestNumber
String custAlternateNumber
String custEmail
String custAddress
String custAddress2
String custCity
String custState
String custZip

String vehicleYear
String vehicleMake
String vehicleModel
String vehicleVin

static hasMany = [glassTypes: GlassType, options: GlassOption]

Date insuranceDateOfLoss
String insuranceCompany
String insurancePolicyNumber
String insuranceClaimNumber
String insuranceDeductible

Date installDate
InstallTime installTime
InstallLocation installLocation
String installCrossStreet1
String installCrossStreet2
String installAddress
String installCity

String notes

Date dateCreated
String soldBy


static constraints = {

    jobType blank: false
    custFirstName blank: false
    custLastName blank: false
    custBestNumber blank: false, size:10..10
    custAlternateNumber nullable: true, sizeMax: 10
    custEmail blank: false, email: true
    custAddress blank: false
    custAddress2 nullable: true
    custCity blank: false
    custState blank: false, size: 2..2
    custZip blank:false, size: 5..5

    vehicleYear blank: false, size:4..4
    vehicleMake blank: false
    vehicleModel blank: false
    vehicleVin blank: false, size:17..17

    glassTypes blank: false
    options blank: false

    insuranceDateOfLoss nullable: true
    insuranceCompany nullable: true
    insurancePolicyNumber nullable: true
    insuranceClaimNumber nullable: true
    insuranceDeductible nullable: true

    installDate blank: false
    installTime blank: false
    installLocation blank: false
    installCrossStreet1 blank: false
    installCrossStreet2 blank: false
    installAddress nullable: true
    installCity nullable: true

    paymentType blank: false
    jobStatus blank: false
    notes nullable: true, size:0..1024
    soldBy blank: false     
}

static belongsTo = SecUser
```

}

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: salesOrderInstance, field: 'soldBy', 'error')} required">
<label for="soldBy">
    <g:message code="salesOrder.soldBy.label" default="Sold By" />
</label>
<g:textField name="soldBy" value="${salesOrderInstance?.soldBy}" default="${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:'username')}" />
<sec:loggedInUserInfo field="username"></sec:loggedInUserInfo>
```

I tried following an example where it uses a Service, but that just left me lost as the example only required one field to be passed. as you can see i have more than one, and some many to one joins. Left me with more questions than answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the question of user's seeing their own data vs an admin seeing everyone's data, [see my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301090/seeing-only-your-own-data-in-grails/13301307#13301307).

As far as associating users to their own data...if the data should belong to a user, simply associate the User domain to said data, as you have already done, but with a slight modification:

```
class SalesOrder {

   static belongsTo = [secUser : SecUser]

}
```

And then add the appropriate mapping to your SecUser class:

```
class SecUser {

   static hasMany = [salesOrders : SalesOrder]

}
```

Then, when you post the data to the server:

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
def save() {

   def authenticatedUser = SecUser.findByUsername(springSecurityService.principal.username)
   def salesOrder = new SalesOrder(params)
   // this assumes you're SecUser and SalesOrder are a 1-to-many bidirectional association
   authenticatedUser.addToSalesOrders(salesOrder)
   authenticatedUser.save()
}
```

There's no need store the info in a hidden field since the same data is available in the controller.  Scaffolding is a great way to get started with a proof of concept.  However, I never use scaffolding anymore.

Comment: I'd give you 1,000 points and a Gold Badge if I could. I've been stuck on that problem for weeks.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help.  You can always up vote it once though.