# Restrict access to subset

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

Amongst others I have a holding, a company and an employee domain class. What is the best practice to make sure that an employee of company A, can only access company A related data? I read about spring security core,filters, criteria, interceptor, etc etc, but now still wondering what is the best solution. What is the typically Grails solution, and should I use redundant keys in my domain classes because of performance reasons?

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301090/seeing-only-your-own-data-in-grailsf

Comment: Hi, we never remove questions, if them have been solved. Otherbody also could have similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still using the Hibernate Filter plugin and still recommend it as one of the best solution I know of (I also answered Sergio's linked question). There are some more advanced plugins, but their complexity require maintenance of the plugins which sometimes seem to fall a bit behind. I'd recommend a company_id per domain class, i.e. use redundant keys, also recommend that you use the excellent Spring Security Core plugin.